# Bootstrap Nav Bar Dropdown Automatically Closes on Mobile Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

So I've spent the last 48 hours trying everything I found under the sun and cannot get anywhere, so I'm leaving it up to all of your fantastic, smart brains.

I just started using bootstrap not too long ago, I have a NAV bar that has 4 items: Home, Services, Download, and Contact.

The Services item is the only one that will have a dropdown.

The dropdown works perfectly on desktop/laptop browsers, but on my phone (android using chrome browser) it doesn't work so great.

On mobile, because of screen size, Bootstrap turns the whole nav bar into a dropdown menu, so the "services" dropdown is inside a parent dropdown.  When I click "services" to get the dropdown menu with all the services, I see for a split second that the dropdown is opening because i see a glimpse of the text, then immediately the parent and services div will close.

```
<!-- start navigation -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('body').on('touchstart.dropdown'.'.dropdown-menu', function(e){e.stopPrpagation(); })
    </script>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top templatemo-nav" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <img src="images/Logo-banner.jpg" height="auto" width="auto" />
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-uppercase">
                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#feature">Computer, Tablet &amp Phone Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">On Site Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Remote Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Managed Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">New &amp Used Computer Sales</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Custom Built Computers</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <!--<li><a href="#pricing">About</a></li>-->
                    <li><a href="#download">Download</a></li>
                    <!--<li><a href="#download">Contact</a></li>-->
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- end navigation -->
```

I've looked up many problems on here, some say to use a javascript function similar to this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        $('.dropdown li, .dropdown a').click(function(e) {
                            e.stopPropagation();
                        });
                    </script>
```

Others say you need to manually show/hide the dropdown.

So far nothing has worked for me.  I'm self taught programmer so as detailed as you can put it would be greatly appreciated. If you need anything else let me know,

Thanks,

Comment: You should put all of your code into a jsfiddle (html/css/js ) so it can be looked at.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v15ha05m/    Well, there's that, but I have absolutely no idea how to get the bootstrap working in there...

Comment: @Daniel Mort. to add bootstrap to your jsfiddle, go here http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

and copy both the css and js into the jsfiddle  "External Resources" portion.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dfnf05wk/    There is the new link.  The drop down doesn't work at all on jsfiddle, however.  There are also a few files like bootstrap.min.css, animate.min.css, jquery.js, wow.min.js, etc files I have saved that are barely readable that are linked in the header.  Wasn't sure how to put them in.